# What is the maximum possible Apache HTTP TimeOut directive?

Tags: apache, http, timeout, max, httpd.conf

What is the **maximum** possible value that Apache2 Web Server allows for it's TimeOut directive in your httpd.conf or apache2.conf (in server config or vhost config) without failing back to the default value?

EDIT: To clarify, what I mean by 'failing back to the default value'.

It appears that when exceeding the upper bound of the directive, the value defining the TimeOut will revert back to 300. An example of this would be setting the TimeOut to 1800 (seconds), the server will continue to keep the request alive for 30 minutes succesfully. Whereas if you were to set the TimeOut to 31536000 (seconds) or 1 year, the server will revert or fail back to the default value of 300 (seconds) and only keeping the request alive for 5 minutes.

References:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout
The default is set to 300 (seconds)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "without failing back to default value?"

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not sure I understand what you mean when you say - "*without failing back to default value?*", I am assuming that you are trying to determine the upper bound for Apache's Timeout directive. I dont believe `org.apache.hc.core5.util.Timeout` enforces an upper bound on its value. If you look at the source for [Timeout](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/master/httpcore5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/core5/util/Timeout.java), you will notice that `timeout` parameter values are Java `long`s. For example -

```
    public static Timeout of(final long duration, final TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        return new Timeout(duration, timeUnit);
    }
```

So I believe that the directive's upper bound theoretically is the upper bound for Java `long`.

That said, please clarify what you mean by - "*without failing back to default value?*"

Comment: Please see the latest edit for clarification on your question